# timezone issue in R, i want to use UTC+0100, even in summer, although CET switches to CEST automatically

Tags: r, timezone, dst, timezone-offset, lubridate

I've got some data with POSIXct timestamps in "CET" (Central European Time = Winter time = UTC+0100) and "CEST" (Central European Summer Time = UTC+0200). Since I've had some trouble with plots and calculations because of that daylight savings time, I want all of the timestamps to be in UTC+0100 time.

Here is an example for my timestamps on switch-back-to-winter-time-day:

```
> tdf$time_posix_vec[1:20]
[1] "2015-10-25 00:00:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 00:15:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 00:30:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 00:45:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 01:00:00 CEST"
 [6] "2015-10-25 01:15:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 01:30:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 01:45:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 02:00:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 02:15:00 CEST"
[11] "2015-10-25 02:30:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 02:45:00 CEST" "2015-10-25 02:00:00 CET"  "2015-10-25 02:15:00 CET"  "2015-10-25 02:30:00 CET" 
[16] "2015-10-25 02:45:00 CET"  "2015-10-25 03:00:00 CET"  "2015-10-25 03:15:00 CET"  "2015-10-25 03:30:00 CET"  "2015-10-25 03:45:00 CET"
```

To demonstrate the issue i picked an example timestamp:

```
> tx <- tdf$time_posix_vec[7]
> tx
[1] "2015-10-25 01:30:00 CEST"
```

I already tried lubridate's with_tz function, but if I use it with "CET", this is what happens:

```
> with_tz(tx, tzone = "CET")
[1] "2015-10-25 01:30:00 CEST"
```

I assume, the timezone handler knows that in my location CET becomes CEST between last week of march and last week of october.

To solve the issue I could use Algeria's timezone, since Algeria uses CET without daylight savings time (as wikipedia told me). However, this could change in the future, and

I wonder if this solution would be a bit unsafe because of that?

```
> with_tz(tx, tzone = "Africa/Algiers")
[1] "2015-10-25 00:30:00 CET"
```

The best way, I thought, would be to use "UTC+1", but the behaviour of with_tz is exactly the opposite of what I expected:

```
> with_tz(tx, tzone = "UTC+1")
[1] "2015-10-24 22:30:00 UTC"
```

to get 00:30:00 I would have to use:

```
> with_tz(tx, tzone = "UTC-1")
[1] "2015-10-25 00:30:00 UTC"
```

but then also the label "UTC" is wrong, because in UTC it would be

```
> with_tz(tx, tzone = "UTC")
[1] "2015-10-24 23:30:00 UTC"
```

- Why is "UTC+1" switching the timestamp to UTC-0100 instead of UTC+0100?
- And is there a function that forces the timestamp to UTC+0100 and also gives puts the correct timezone label to the timestamp, so the result would be `"2015-10-25 00:30:00 UTC+1"`?

Thanks in advance,

greetings, Peter

Comment: You could try converting to POSIXlt, specifying the desired timezone and then convert back to POSIXct still specifying the desired timezone.  Not the best but potentially a work around.  I have found it is set the timezone, with tz=, at the time of import, it prevents many problems later on.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution: now I use

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct("2016-07-12 17:43","Etc/GMT-1")
```

for example. It confused me that `GMT-1` is the same as `UTC+0100`, they seem to turn around the sign at bsd style timezones.